# Why does karma not find my karma.conf.js file when I run my Jasmine tests from Visual Studio?

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine, visual-studio-2019

After having used C# unit tests for years, I am writing and running Javascript unit tests for the first time using Visual Studio 2019.  I'm following along with this guide: https://jimblizzard.wordpress.com/2018/01/20/unit-testing-your-javascript-code/

So far, I have everything working, but when I launch the tests from the "Test Explorer" window in Visual Studio, I get errors indicating that the objects created in my Javascript files are undefined.

I get this error in spite of the fact that when I run my tests from the command line with `karma start`, the tests pass.

I've noticed that even if the karma.conf.js file is syntactically malformed, I get the same error.  I would have expected to get a syntax error, so that suggests that karma is not reading my karma.conf.js file, which is in the root folder of my ASP.net project.

What could I be doing wrong that when karma launches from the command line, the tests pass, but when it launches from the Visual Studio Test Explorer, I get errors and it appears that my karma.conf.js file is ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

Per the guide that I linked, I am using the Chutzpah test runner to launch my tests within Visual Studio 2019.  It looks like Chutzpah requires that I designate the locations of my test files with reference comments like so:

///

This fixed the problem for me!